# Fxcop custom rule to check name of derived class ends with base class name

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop

I am trying to develop a custom `fxcop` rule to check name of derived class ending with the base class name.

My main concerned is  there any property in `Fxcop.Sdk` to know whether that particular class is derived from any of the base class? If yes then How ?

How can I implement this rule ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes you can. Take a look at the following image:

[image]

What you see here is a screenshot from [introspector](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/introspector.html), which is a tool that helps you develop FxCop rules.

As you can see each class has a Property `BaseType` and `BaseClass`. You can use those to check if the class inherits from anything.

Do note that in the Introspection-model, for example Classes that are not derived from anything are shown to be derived from `Object`.

You could skip those (and any other possible faults):

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(TypeNode type)
{
    ClassNode classNode = type as ClassNode;
    if (classNode == null)
        return;
    if (classNode.BaseType == null)
        return;
    if (classNode.BaseType == FrameworkTypes.Object)
        return;

    // Namechecking logic

    return Problems;
}
```

Comment: VS studio is showing error in the Third conditional statement for NodeType.Object that Fxcop.Sdk do not contain defination for Object.

Comment: I actually wrote it off the top of my hat, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For such need, you can use the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) that let's write custom code rules for .NET code through C# LINQ queries. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of this tool*

For example, to write a custom rule to *check name of derived class ends with base class name*, it is as simple as:

```
// <Name>Derived class name must ends with base class name</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from t in Application.Types
where t.IsClass
let baseClass = t.BaseClass
where !baseClass.IsThirdParty // Skip all .NET Fx base classes, like System.Object
where !t.SimpleName.EndsWith(baseClass.SimpleName)
select new {t, baseClass }
```

Such rule can be edited live, and compiled/executed immediately after each keystroke, within Visual Studio.

[image]

Around [200 of such LINQ query rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are provided per default. Rules violation [can be seen live in VisualStudio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx), or [in a report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule) created during the CI process.